# Using custom width and height, jQuery Mobile Dialog center to screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, dialog, modal-dialog

I have created app using jQuery Mobile and need to get a Dialog box when button is clicked. The Dialog box should be center aligned of the screen when  i have specified the width and height of the Dialog. Please check current [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/wGpsa/) version.

Code as follows.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page1"> 
    <button data-theme="a" id="submit-button-1">Open Dialog</button>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <p>This is popup</p>
    </div>
</div>


$('#submit-button-1').click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page2'), 'pop', false, true); 
});




#page2 {
     width:150px;
     height:150px;
     border: #f00 solid 1px; 
     margin:20px 100px;
}
```

I changed the `margin: 20px auto;` but no luck.

Need to know one more thing, When I Click on the button, Dialog box is appeared on the center of screen. But it loads as separete page, I mean clicked button page is removed by Dialog. How to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "position: relative":

```
margin:20px auto;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Almost there, Need to know one more thing, When i Click on the button Dialog box appear on the center of screen. But it loads as separete page, I mean clicked button page is removed by Dialog. How to avoid this.

Comment: @Sameera, When you're using changePage you do exactly that. Change the page. I guess you could use "page2" as a normal div instead of a page. That would, however, make the items behind the popup clickable. I updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Naning/wGpsa/14/